# How to calculate "AIC" in a svyglm model?

Tags: r, survey

I have this model and I need to calculate "AIC" to make model selection, my problem is that when I run the model "AIC" appears as "NA".

```
MODEL= svyglm(formula = Asiste ~ afro + sexo + E27 + JovenActivo + hijos + 
jefe + LN_YSVL_sin_joven_prom + aniosed + climaeducativo + 
Mdeo + icv2 + TV + Computadora + Telefono + Internet + Cable + 
Calefon + DVD + Microhondas + Aire + Auto_o_moto + Secadora + 
Madre_ausente + Internet + TV + Lavavajillas + Refrigerador + 
climaeducativo + Actividad_del_Jefe + Hacinamiento, family = quasibinomial(link =      
"logit"), 
data = Personas.con.muestra, design = diseño_personas_14_17, 
subset = (Stratum != 0))

MODEL$aic
[1] NA
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!! Natalia

Comment: Searching the `survey` package documentation http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf , I see no mention of "AIC" or "Akaike". Maybe you want to run `AIC(MODEL)`?

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that a quasibinomial fit should produce an AIC estimate? (Even if AIC for quasi-families were well-defined, the procedure you propose is still statistically dubious.) Search the R-help Archive if you doubt my word. Be sure to pay special attention to postings by Lumley and Harrell.

Comment: @Frank. `svyglm` will have a list element named "aic", but it is only computed for regular families, and always is NA for quasi- families.

Comment: Thanks for comment I arlready solve it! Its no possible get AIC in svyglm because svyglm dont use the same estimator that glm, so to choose de model is necessary doit with for example backward by hand. Thanks!

Comment: @Natuk this recently changed  http://notstatschat.tumblr.com/post/94804517126/survey-package-update

Answer (score 0):

There is now an `AIC.svyglm` function in the `survey` package, based on the new method developed by Lumley & Scott ([2015](https://doi.org/10.1093/jssam/smu021)).  Basically, the $2p$ penalty needs to depend on the weights (higher weights means higher penalty) and on the increased variance due to clustering (more uncertainty means higher penalty)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
summary(MODEL)$aic
```